# When I should use before report and when i should use after report in oracle xml publisher?

Tags: oracle, triggers, xml-publisher

What is the difference between using a before report and after report in xml publisher?, I don't understand when i should use the specific trigger.

Answer (score 0):

It is exactly as the name describes.

The beforeReport trigger is executed before the report is called.  For example you might use this to set profile context that is required to call an API or interface program.

The afterReport trigger runs after the report is executed.  This is useful, again as an example, to call to bursting program to email the report after it has been created.